# Trigger click after page reload

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, settimeout

In a web app I am working on, I have a button that when clicked, reloads the page... Sort of a 'restart'.

How can I trigger the 'start' button after the page is reloaded?

Heres what Ive not (which is not working)

```
                $('.restart').click(function () {
                location.reload();
                 setTimeout(function () { 
                     $('.get_started').trigger('click'); 
                     }, 3000);
                });
```

Comment: You cannot pass JavaScript from one page session to another. You'll have to use a `document.ready` handler, something with local storage or a cookie, or a server-side solution.

Comment: You can add a parameter to url and if parameter is present you know that start has to be triggered.

Answer (score 1):

As @genesiss noted I could add a URL parameter after the reload like:

```
$('.restart').click(function () {
    window.location.href = window.location.href.replace( /[\?#].*|$/, "?restart" );
});
```

Then call up that parameter after the page loads:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if (window.location.search.indexOf('restart') > -1) {
    setTimeout(function () { 
        $('.get_started').trigger('click'); 
        }, 3000);
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

Take timeout part out and put it inside document ready block, like this -

```
$(function(){

    setTimeout(function () { 
        $('.get_started').trigger('click'); 
    }, 3000);

});
```